# How to use a CRUD with RSpec in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, factory-bot

i am a newbie in RSpec gem.so please anyone can tell me that how I can create an index, create, show, delete and update method in my RSpec test controller.

Please help me!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with controller testing for a while, unlike models there seems to be very few examples as to how to do it properly. It's worth remembering the only thing you should be testing when you test controllers is that it routes you to the right place and presents you with the right information, so the majority of your tests will be testing the status code you receive and if any flash messages are set.

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

The above link gives you a good example for how to get started with an index action test. The show test will be very similar. When testing create and delete tests, you'll need to test what happens when the create / delete action succeeds and fails:

```
allow(Model).to receive(:save).and_return true
  test that flash message is set and redirect happens

allow(Model).to receive(:save).and_return false
  test that flash error is set and render :new happens
```